# Cannot Use Inline Editing On Custom Fields

Tags: contacts, custom-fields

After upgrading to CiviCRM to 4.7 we cannot use the inline editing for one of our sets of custom fields.  You can see on the *Application Fields* that they cannot be edited with the inline editor.

[image: Application Fields Cannot Be Edited]

When you look at the *Legacy Fields* they can be edited with inline editing. [image]

I have cleared caches and turned off extensions to see if that would change anything and it did not.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you by any chance, change the custom field type recently? Have you tried going to these fields, and then simply, resaving it again?

Comment: @Kristine I did not change the fields.  The only change was the upgrade from 4.6 to 4.7. The fields work perfectly if I do the full page edit.  I did as you suggested with saving the fields again and this did not have any change.

Comment: Please do check the in_selector field in the civicrm_custom_field table? I stumbled over that one before. It should be set to 1.

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: Did you check for messages in the browser console? If you have javascript issues, they might show up there.

Comment: Thank you for all the thoughts/questions.  The in_selector value is '0'. I checked and this is the same for fields that can be edited and those that are not working.  --  We are using Drupal 7. -- When I look at the console there are no JS errors but lots of  'violation's. (https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/onlinesharing18/Screen+Shot+2017-05-02+at+9.23.14+AM.png). Thanks!